# Magento: why are ordered items duplicated in this variable?

Tags: php, magento

When I load an order by its order number, the array returned contains the same items twice.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(12345);
$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();
```

If the order contains one item, then, `count($orderItems)` will be 2 and the content in each of the array index will be idential. What's going on?

I tried the following to load an order as well, but it did not even work on Magento Enterprise 1.11.2.0.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(12345);
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems()
```

Comment: Are you certain the script is not executing twice, such as because of a faulty rewrite rule or redirect? Check you web server log to see if it is being hit twice for each.

Comment: Hm, I don't see anything in system.log. How would a script executing twice cause this? `$order`'s content is duplicated within right as it is created. I've tried loading orders this way on the sale confirmation page and PDF invoice generation page. In both instances, the array is duplicated in content. So, I'm currently doing `if ($i%2==0)` to get unique items but I have a feeling this is bound to fail at some point when duplicates are no longer present..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using configurable products, magento duplicates order items in database table of sales_flat_order_item.

If you use $order->getAllVisibleItems() you will get what you want.

Comment: Although it's been long since I've figured this out, I'll mark your answer so that it may help others. `$order->getAllVisibleItems()` retrieves all items as displayed on the frontend and backend (admin). For more information, please see `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::getAllVisibleItems()`.